# Group by column A but comparing column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This one has had me stumped for the last few hours and at this stage I think I need some help...

I need to compare multiple groups from a single table and to identify where items listed in col B match.  For example: -

```
Col A...............Col B
John................Apple
John................Orange
John................Banana
Mary................Orange
Mary................Strawberry
David...............Apple
David...............Orange
David...............Banana
```

I want 'John' and 'David' returned because their items in col B match.  Hope this makes sense!
Thanks in advance!
G

Comment: It helps to have expected output defined very explicitly.  You've got sample input above.  Try writing sample output in the exact format you'd like.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24435/1/0) for this solution, so that you can play with it yourself.

```
 select A.ColA Person1, B.ColA Person2
    from (select ColA, count(ColB) CountBs
          from tbl
          group by ColA) G1
    join (select ColA, count(ColB) CountBs
          from tbl
          group by ColA) G2 on G1.ColA < G2.ColA
                           and G1.CountBs = G2.CountBs
    join tbl A on A.ColA = G1.ColA
    join tbl B on B.ColA = G2.ColA and A.ColB = B.ColB
group by A.ColA, B.ColA, G1.CountBs
having count(distinct A.ColB) = G1.CountBs

-- subqueries G1 and G2 are the same and count the expected colB's per colA
-- G1 and G2 are joined together to get the candidate matches
--    of ColA with the same number of ColB's
-- we then use G1 and G2 to join into tbl, and further join
--    between A and B where the ColB's match
-- finally, we count the matches between A and B and make sure the counts match
--    the expected count of B's for the pairing
```

Comment: if you add these records: 
Tim....Apple
Jim....Orange
Jim....Banana
It adds Jim to the return set.

Comment: @JTC Thanks. fixed now. That's peer review for you :)

Comment: What if there were 3 items in ColA that had shared ColB values?

Comment: @diana - Shared my SQL Fiddle. It lists all the combination pairs.

Answer (score 0):

All the people who have an item in column b that is matched to more than on person (I'm assuming you are looking for possibly more than just 2 matches?):

```
SELECT tableName.ColA, tableName.ColB
FROM (SELECT ColB
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY ColB
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) fruits
INNER JOIN tableName ON fruits.ColB = tableName.ColB
ORDER BY tableName.ColB, tableName.ColA
```

Answer (score 0):

ColA1 matches ColA2 if:
Count (ColA1) = Count (ColA2) = Count (ColA1 x ColA2)

This approach attempts to optimize query speed.

Materialize the raw count as it is used more than once and can declare a PK.
(a CTE is just syntax and is evaluated)

The where RA.rawcount = RB.rawcount allows for only evaluate the join if the counts are equal.  And the query plan indicates that it is performed first.

```
create table #rawcount
(ColA varchar(50) not null primary key, rawcount int  not null)  
insert into #rawcount
select   [ColA], COUNT(*) as  [rawCount]
from     [tbl]
group by [ColA]
order by [ColA]

select a.ColA as ColA1, b.ColA as ColA2, COUNT(*) [matchcount]
from tbl A
join tbl B
 on  a.ColB = b.ColB 
 and a.ColA < b.ColA
join #rawcount RA 
 on  RA.ColA = A.ColA
join #rawcount RB 
 on  RB.ColA = B.ColA
where RA.rawcount = RB.rawcount  -- only evaluate if count same
group by a.ColA, b.ColA, RA.rawcount
having COUNT(*) = RA.rawcount
```